# infopath form in sharepoint can't lookup from SQL

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, infopath

I've made a simple form in infopath, that looks up information in SQL server.
Using the design tool, I can fill in the form and submit it.  All info from SQL server is being retrieved.
The SQL server is used in many different scenario's and accessible through different means. In the first phase I'm using a read/write account to connect to the database.

When I publish it to sharepoint (2010), I get an error the first time the SQL data is being requested.
I get an error that refers to the windows error logs; but I do not have access to the sharepoint environment.
The sharepoint is installed in the same forest, it should be able to get a connection to our sql server.

are the BCS (business connectivity services) necessary for this kind of action?
are there any other reasons why this could fail?

Answer (score 0):

If it's working on your machine in debug mode but not on the server I would check two settings:

- Authentication settings as you might be getting a [double hop problem](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/knowledgecast/archive/2007/01/31/the-double-hop-problem.aspx).
- Security on database, make sure the user has access to the database

Comment: The SQL data connection is through an ODC that contains a sql user in plain-text (still testing). This means i shouldn't be using impersonation.

Comment: Only other thing I could think of then would be if you're using SQL Express, make sure that remote connections are allowed.

Comment: edited my question to clarify that's it's a full blown sql server and user.